# States VLOOKUP on a continuously added to Google Sheet

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, spreadsheet

Ok I have been fighting this for a few days now... and ever time I think I have it I don't.

I have a Google Sheet that is continuously being added to from different sources. It is collecting orders from several e-comm outlets. I organize the data to come in generally how I need it from the sources. I them am taking that data and putting it into Data Studio. But since the sources are different, the State field comes in in many different formats, but I need them to all be the same, preferably abbreviations. I have been trying to do a VLOOKUP on a Named Range created in a separate sheet that has all the variations of states that I have seen in column 2 and the abbreviated version in column 1. Then in my main data sheet I am doing a big formula in row 1 of the column that I am trying to output the state abbreviations.

Here is the formula:
`=ArrayFormula(IF(ROW(B:B)=1, "Shipping State Abbv", IF(C:C = "US", IFERROR(VLOOKUP(B:B, StatesList, 1, TRUE), B:B), B:B)))`

Note: There are some countries other than US, so if it is not US I just want the value from Column C.

I have created a small sample of data that is showing what is happening [here](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/11B2E_D9Jwt6arsdBlbyc_nYBr1Chpfy_vqdWZGwykHc/edit#gid=0). If someone could please help me figure out what is wrong and help me fix it that would be fantastic!

Another Note: The sheet States List 2 is another format for laying out the different versions of the states, if that could utilized instead, that may be nicer to maintain. Basically find the value in the sheet and use column 1 as the returned value.

Comment: why would you lock the sheet if you want people to help ?

Comment: @nabais that was unintended. Fixed.

Comment: I gave comment access to anyone with the link now. I can give edit access if needed, but I don't want to lose track of what is going on in the sheet. Thanks for any and all help!!

Comment: please create a copy of your sheet with dummy but reliable data and update the question with your new link

Comment: I can just make it editable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think I found what was going on, as your vlookup was not doing a very good job.

Basically I just copied the values from `States List` to `States List 2` and swapped the columns A and B on the States List 2:

[image]

Then updated the value of the function to this:

`={"Shipping State Abbv"; ARRAYFORMULA(IF(LEN(A2:A),if(C2:C = "US",VLOOKUP(upper(B2:B), 'States List 2'!A:B,2,FALSE),C:C),))}`

[image]

Let me know if you manage to succeed.

Comment: Close!! I implemented your stuff into my sheet the only issue is the non US country. Row 10 should just output "JERSEY" since it is GB and not US.

Comment: Ok I got it now! `={"Shipping State Abbv"; ARRAYFORMULA(IF(LEN(A2:A), IF(C2:C = "US", VLOOKUP(upper(B2:B), 'States List'!A:B, 2, FALSE), B2:B),))}`. Just a minor tweak to if the C2:C was not US.

Comment: Good, in my opinion the vlookup was the one with the problem as it was giving misleading values, but i managed to see also the country code and corrected that as well, don't forget to upvote or mark the answer as accepted if it helped you solving the problem

Comment: Done and Done! Wish I would have posted to here days ago... Thank you so much @nabais